# Container in navbar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, web

I am writing my own Bootstrap related website but I have a problem
I have:

- class "navbar"
- class "cointeiner"

My code:

```
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sklep internetowy</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toogle="collapse" data-targer="#navbar-menu">
            
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"> Test1 </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"> Test2 </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"> Test3 </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"> Test4 </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">aaa</div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">bbb</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My main.css

```
.navbar {
background-color: #123456;
min-width: 60px;
}
```

The container is located in the navigation bar. I was looking for a problem in my code, but can't see it. I've watched a lot of YouTube videos and the code is the same or very similar.

[Presentation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs8pL.png)

Comment: You misspelled container as cointeiner. It doesn't make sense. If you have wrong css then it could affect. Please make all correct names.

Comment: Please could you give a codesandbox to test it?

Comment: Thanks @development-ninja! It works! I didn't see it and didn't pay attention to it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh great, it was issue? haha glad to hear you solved issue. it would be helpful to upvote to my comment. thanks.